# How can I get the size of an Amazon S3 bucket using Python (Boto lib)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'd like to get the size (in **bytes**, and # of keys) of an Amazon S3 bucket.
I'm looking for an **efficient** way to get the size of bucket.

One possible way(which is **NOT** efficient): I can get the key list of the bucket and sum up the size of each key. This is inefficient when I have thousand of key because I have to look for each key's size.

Is there any **efficient** solution??

The following code is not what I looking for (because it's not efficient):

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket("bucket_name")
total_size = 0
for key in bucket.list():
   total_size += key.size
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be direct call to do that. You can iterate through the keys and sum up.

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket(self.container)
size = 0
for key in bucket.list():
   size += key.size
```

This should be used only if the bucket has a small number of keys and the calculation is not performed very often.

Check [this](https://serverfault.com/a/288299/79224) (Not Boto) for a more useful option.

Comment: I have tried this solution. It is not efficient. I am looking for an efficient solution. anyway thanks.

Comment: There is no other way to do it, unfortunately.  The S3 API just doesn't provide a mechanism to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found something, you can get the number of keys in a bucket by using these codes:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket("bucket_name")
number_of_keys = len(bucket.get_all_keys())})
```

---

> **I still need size of *bucket* (in bytes) ??**

---

Comment: get_all_keys (contrary to what the name suggests) will only return a maximum of 1000 keys at a time, so this breaks down if you have more keys than that in a bucket.